# Quicktab visibility by programing

Tags: users, blocks

I have a **Quicktab** with 2 tabs. The block is placed in **user profile**.

Now I want to show one of the blocks only when the user visits his own profile and hide it when he is visiting other profiles. How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you can use **[hook_quicktabs_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!quicktabs!quicktabs.api.php/function/hook_quicktabs_alter/7)**

```
    /**
     * Implementing hook_quicktabs_alter
     * @param type $quicktabs
     */
    function MODULE_NAME_quicktabs_alter(&$quicktabs) {
        global $user;
        foreach ($quicktabs->tabs as $key => $tab) {
            if ($tab['title'] == 'Tab1' && arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && $user->uid == arg(1)) {//check condition as per your requirement
                unset($quicktabs->tabs[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, But this will affect both of the tabs of the quicktab. What i want is to be able to show only one of the tabs if the condition meet.

Comment: You mean to say you have only one block with 2 tabs. You want to hide the tab based on some requirement?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Where should I put this? Shall I write a module?

Comment: Yes inside any custom .module file. If you dont have the custom module then create one. Use this link as [reference](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7) OR [Building a Drupal 7 Module](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-drupal-7-module-show-latest-nodes/)

Comment: I got some time to deal with this answer. the URL for user profiles in may case is /users/USERNAME so the arg(0) should be equal to 'users'. So is_numeric is not the case cause arg(1) is the username and is not numeric. Due to this $user->uid will never be equal to arg(1).  How shall I change the condition if I got all correct?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to put that code right where you want the quicktab to render:

```
<?php
// Current user uid.
global $user;
$userUid = $user->uid;

// Uid of the user's viewed profile.
$userUidViewedProfile = $arg(1)

// Condition if current userId = userId's viewed profile. If it is, render the quicktab.
if ($userUid == $userUidViewedProfile)
{
    $block = module_invoke('quicktabs', 'block_view', 'machine_name'); // Only change the machine name here,
    print render($block);
}
?>
```

Comment: This works for the whole block. I want one of the tabs to be checked like this.